# Convergence of $\sum_{a\in \mathbb{N}^n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right)^{-\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For which $\alpha$ (depending on $n$) does
$$\sum_{a\in \mathbb{N}^n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right)^{-\alpha}$$
converge?

Examples:

For $n=1$ the series turns out to be
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^{2\alpha}}$$
so we know that it is convergent for $\alpha>1/2$.

In case $n=2$ we have convergence for $\alpha>1$ which can be shown by solving
$$\int_{x^2+y^2 \ge 1} \frac{dx dy}{(x^2+y^2)^\alpha}$$
using polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the largest integer $N$ in a tuple, there are a constant ($n$) number of places where it can occur, and all other entries can be $\leq N$. Over all tuples that have largest integer $N$ appearing, both the smallest and largest possible value of the terms in your series are on the order of $O(N^{-2\alpha})$ since $n$ is a constant. The total number of tuples whose largest entry is $N$ is $N^n - (N-1)^n = O(N^{n-1})$. So your series grows proportional to $\sum_N N^{-2 \alpha + n - 1}$. So your series converges if and only if $-2 \alpha + n < 0$, i.e. $\alpha > n/2$.